# appendChild does not work. New to Javascript

Tags: javascript, appendchild, textnode

I'm new to JavaScript and I currently have an assignment. One question asks us to attach a new textNode to the `<p>` tag. But my appendChild doesn't want to work.  All my other code works fine and does what it's supposed to. Obviously I am doing something wrong.

**EDIT:**
In my console I am receiving an error: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'appendChild' of null

```
<head>
<style type="text/css">
#demo {
font-family: Verdana, Geneva, sans-serif;
font-size: 14px;
font-style: italic;
background-color: #996;
height: 25px;
width: 400px;
padding: 20px;
}
</style>
</head>

<body>

<p id = "demo">Existential div asks: &quot;Why I am I here?&quot;</p>

<script>

document.title="Tag, you're it!";

var parent=document.body;
var child=document.getElementById("demo");
parent.removeChild(child);

var para=document.createElement("p");
var node=document.createTextNode("The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog.");
para.appendChild(node);

var element=document.getElementById("demo");
element.appendChild(para);


with(para){
color: "#FFF";
fontFamily : "Arial";
backgroundColor: "#345";
fontSize: "30px";
textAlign: "center";
width: "600px";
height: "200px";
padding: "20px";
margin: "0px auto";
};


</script>
</body>
```

Comment: Thanks changed the with. And yes, I am getting an error in the console. Forgot to mention in in the main post. It says: "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'appendChild' of null"

Comment: You're removing the paragraph so `var element = document.getElementById("demo");` will fail.

Comment: I'm not trying to append to "demo". After demo is removed I create a new element, "p". And then I try to append the new textNode to "p". So should I change it from `var element=document.getElementById("demo");` to `var element=document.getElementById("p")` ??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your logic is wrong.

You remove the element called demo in these lines

```
var child=document.getElementById("demo");
parent.removeChild(child);
```

You then try to append a child node to the node you've just removed here:

```
var element=document.getElementById("demo");
element.appendChild(para);
```

You can't append an element to an element that no longer exists. If you delete the `removeChild` line, then everything should work.

Also, your with block is wrong, you need to change it to:

```
with(para.style){
    color = "#FFF";
    fontFamily = "Arial";
    backgroundColor = "#345";
    fontSize = "30px";
    textAlign = "center";
    width = "600px";
    height = "200px";
    padding = "20px";
    margin = "0px auto";
};
```

After that, everything should be good.

Comment: My with isn't being applied. Even with the changes

Comment: Apologies, my mistake, you need to use = rather than :. I've updated my answer to show that.

Answer (score 3):

First, you remove the element, and later on, you try to add something after that. Since it's removed, it can't be found in the DOM anymore.

```
var child=document.getElementById("demo");
parent.removeChild(child);

var element=document.getElementById("demo"); // returns nothing, since it was removed
element.appendChild(para);
```

So, simply don't remove that element if you don't want to. [JSFiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/nSy5H/).

Comment: Okay, I see what I was doing wrong. But how do I fix it? Below is the questions from the assignment where this is coming from: 2.1 Change the document title to “Tag, you’re it!” (Which was successful)
2.2 Remove the element with the selector id “demo” by accessing the DOM (hat was successful as well)
2.3 Create a new paragraph element “p” using javascript (that I did as well)
2.4 Create and attach a textnode to the element in 2.3 with the following text: "The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog."

Comment: If you just want the text to be displayed (but not inside the DOM element), you can simply append it to the `document.body` ([Updated JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/nSy5H/1/)) .

Answer (score 2):

You are removing the element here

```
var child=document.getElementById("demo");
parent.removeChild(child);
```

and then trying to use it here:

```
var element=document.getElementById("demo");
element.appendChild(para);
```

Answer (score 1):

You're removing demo, then trying to reference it later. See this jsFiddle for a cleaner way to do what you appear to be trying, even after destroying p#demo.

http://jsfiddle.net/FzBrS/

```
document.title="Tag, you're it!";

var demo = document.getElementById("demo");
demo.parentNode.removeChild(demo);
var p = document.createElement("p");

document.body.appendChild(p);

var tn = document.createTextNode("The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog.");
p.appendChild(tn);
```

Answer (score 1):

You are removing the `<p id="demo">` (which is held by the variable child)
and then you are trying to add a child to this element (which is already removed)

You can either not remove this element, or add the `para` element to `parent`

1. remove this line: `var element=document.getElementById("demo");`
2. replace `element.appendChild(para);` with `parent.appendChild(para);`

and everything will work correctly.

Comment: That works! The only problem I have now is that the styling that was stated in the with statement is not being applied.

Comment: I'm not sure with() is used here in the correct context.<br/>
I would rather use add after `var para=document.createElement('p')` something like<br/>
`para.style.color = '#fff';  <br/>
para.style.fontFamily='Arial'; <br/> 
para.style.backgroundColor='#345'`   <br/>
and so on and so forth

Comment: If I could do that I would, but our assignment that we got is specifically says that we have to use with()

Answer (score 0):

Your `with` block contains syntax errors, which is causing the script to not run at all.

Change that block to this:

```
with(para.style) {
    color = "#fff";
    fontFamily = "Arial";
    // and so on
}
```